# Add value of edittext and textview together and displaying total in text view

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple android app, which has and editText field and a textView field, the values within these fields are only numeric.

I have created a button which on selecting, I would like the value of the edit text and text view to be added together, I would then like the editText to change to a value of '0' and teh total to be displayed in the textView.

For example if the editText has a value of 10 and the textView has a value of 20 on pressing the button the total of 30 is displayed in the textView and the value of the editText displays 0.

Here is my code so far, when I press the button at the moment the app crashes so I am not confident that I have coded correctly.  I am new to java.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class durood extends Activity{

TextView txtCount;
TextView totalCount;
EditText enteramount;
Button btnCount;
Button addtotal1;
Button addtotal2;
Button cleartotal;
static int count=0;
double x=0;
double y=0;
double z=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// The activity is being created.
setContentView(R.layout.durood);

enteramount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enteramount);
totalCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalCount);
addtotal1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addtototal1);
addtotal2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addtototal2);


//add to total 1
addtotal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

x=Double.parseDouble(enteramount.getText().toString());
y=Double.parseDouble(totalCount.getText().toString());
z=x+y;
totalCount.setText(Double.toString(z));
}


});
```

LogCat

```
12-30 23:52:11.098: W/Trace(615): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d332e8 that was originally bound here
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d332e8 that was originally bound here
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-30 23:52:11.129: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615): null
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d332e8 that was originally bound here
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-30 23:52:11.238: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-30 23:52:11.272: W/ActivityManager(290): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fb7e78
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d32ef0 that was originally bound here
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d32ef0 that was originally bound here
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-30 23:52:11.328: E/ActivityThread(615):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615): null
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d32ef0 that was originally bound here
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-30 23:52:11.398: E/StrictMode(615):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-30 23:52:11.448: W/ActivityManager(290): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f92598
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/dmute"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
 android:minHeight="30dp"
 android:minWidth="48dp"
 android:text="Mute" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/dreset"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="198dp"
 android:minHeight="30dp"
 android:minWidth="48dp"
 android:text="Reset" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:paddingTop="20dp" >

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/dcount"
 android:layout_width="0dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="90"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:text="Numbers"
 android:textSize="25sp" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/addtototal1"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="5"
 android:text="+ to Total" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingTop="20dp" >

  <EditText
  android:id="@+id/enteramount"
  android:layout_width="0dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_weight="90"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:hint="Enter Amount"
  android:inputType="number"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textSize="25sp" />

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/addtototal2"
  style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="5"
  android:text="+ to Total" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:paddingTop="20dp" >

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/totalCount"
 android:layout_width="0dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:layout_weight="80"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textSize="25sp" />

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/cleartotal"
  style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Clear" />

 </LinearLayout>

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/dclick"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  android:height="120dp"
  android:width="250dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If the app crashes you get a stack trace from _LogCat_, include it here

Comment: Do you ever set the button to a view in your layout?

Comment: Where is your `onCreate(...)` method for your `Activity` and where do you call `setContentView(...)`?

Comment: @Squonk I left that bit out, I have put it in now though...

Comment: @codeMagic no the button is not set to a view

Comment: Logcat added, it goes crazy when I press the add to total button

Comment: Then that may be a problem if it isn't initialized

Comment: Is that all you are doing in your `onClick()` or is there more to that method?

Comment: I dont think the crash is because of your button. There might be something in the button's click that you have not added here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize Your button addtotal1:

```
    addtotal1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
```

before You could set onClickListener.

### EDIT

Your xml EditText has only the inputType "number", so the user can´t put some decimal values. If You want it like this, You don´t need double variables. Instead of double, use int, so Your result is without showing decimal point:

```
       public class durood extends Activity{

         private TextView txtCount;
         private TextView totalCount;
         private EditText enteramount;
         private Button btnCount;
         private Button addtotal1;
         private Button addtotal2;
         private Button cleartotal;
         private static int count=0;
         private int x=0;
         private int y=0;
         private int z=0;

          @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // The activity is being created.
            setContentView(R.layout.durood);

            enteramount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enteramount);
            totalCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalCount);
            addtotal1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addtototal1);
            addtotal2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addtototal2);


            //add to total 1
            addtotal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {

              x=Integer.parseInt(enteramount.getText().toString());
              y=Integer.parseInt(totalCount.getText().toString());
              z=x+y;
              totalCount.setText(Integer.toString(z));
              //to set value of enteramount to 0
              enteramount.setText("0"); //or enteramaount.setText("") if You want show nothing
            }


           });
```

Comment: yeah I did this already, forgot to add it to the code above which I extracted, thanks for pointing out

Comment: ok, if this was not the reason, I can´t find the bug. Your code looks good, and the stack trace doesn´t show a mistake made by yourself. Please post your durood.xml, maybe there is a mistake or a thing You could do better.

Comment: seems good too....what happens if you delete your style-attributes inside your buttons? Try it, maybe something is wrong with Your stlye-definitions.

Comment: It works now! I didn't update the xml... I made some adjustments to the code seems that the textview has to show some value otherwise the add total does not work.  However the edit textfield does not go to zero when the values are added - it stays the same and teh total in textview is displayed to 1 decimal point - I don't need this, any idease how to get rid of it?

Comment: see my edit. If You don´t want to show decimal point, use integer instead of double. You don´t need double, because the user can´t set a decimal into the edittext

Comment: no problem :)...and don´t forget to check the input before calculating like in this post below from Mehul Ranpara (but in your case with int, not double). If Your edit text is not filled with a value, You even would get an exception if You don´t check it before.

Answer (score 2):

check the condition like this way before converting to Double...

```
if(enteramount.getText().toString().length()>0)
{
   x=Double.parseDouble(enteramount.getText().toString());
}
if(totalCount.getText().toString().length()>0)
{
   y=Double.parseDouble(totalCount.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mehul, this really helped me out!